# Why is xcode crashing everytime I try to link an animation to a SpriteNode?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I'm currently trying to make a platform game thanks to SWIFT and SKSpriteKit. Everything works fine until I try to make a running animation for my hero.

I'm using the GameScene SpriteKit Scene File (GameScene.sks). I insert an animated textures on my hero sprite. It's working correctly. 
[image]

The thing is I need to export this animation in order to call it when the screen is touched. Therefore I select it, and click on the "convert to reference button" and then create a new sks file (HeroActions.sks).

[image]

What I need to do next is to attach it to a node (the hero spriteNode to be precise). Thus I click on the select button and choose the GameScene.sks file. The hero node (the magician) appears within the scene canvas.
[image]

But... when I click on it Xcode crashes with the following error:

> Process:               Xcode [1346] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               10.2.1 (14490.122) Build
>   Info:            IDEFrameworks-14490122000000000~6 App Item ID:
>   497799835 App External ID:       830924854 Code Type:
>   X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChI9h.jpg) Responsible:
>   Xcode [1346] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2019-06-26 23:17:56.835 +0200 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F132) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   44809473-B612-9FC6-17F2-DD705F0D08C6
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 1400 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4 Termination Reason:
>   Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4 Terminating Process:   exc handler [1346]
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 10E1001
>   Crashing on exception: The window has been marked as needing another
>   Layout Window pass, but it has already had more Layout Window passes
>   than there are views in the window.
>
> Application Specific Backtrace 1: 0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff3d7dccfd __exceptionPreprocess + 256 1   DVTFoundation
>   0x000000010e0633f6 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 274 2
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff67e86a17
>   objc_exception_throw + 48 3   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff3d7dcb2f +[NSException raise:format:] + 201 4   AppKit
>   0x00007fff3ae2ec3b -[NSWindow(NSDisplayCycle)
>   _postWindowNeedsLayoutUnlessPostingDisabled] + 1522 5   AppKit                              0x00007fff3ae2e5e

I know it is a hard one and I tried a lot of different things (reboot, remake the animation, replace the image files which are inside an atlas,...). What's going on?